# Languages with auto-updatable variables

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, graph-algorithm

Is somewhere exists programming languages with auto-updatable variables.
For example:

```
a = 100
b = a * 3 + 1    // 301
c = sin(b) + a   // 99.1428
```

After modifying 'a': a = 105, corresponding variables automatically recalculated:

```
b: 316
c: 104.3053
```

If such languages exists, what approaches are used to implement this behavior?

Comment: Excel just does that. I assume they establish a dependency graph when parsing the expressions. You can check that circular references are detected.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is deferred evaluation. It's common in spreadsheet applications. I think the R language also allows for something like that.

You can implement it in almost any language.

The usual approach is that you define a terminator class (say Number) and override the operators (if the language supports it, like c++, C# or python) to return nodes in an tree. So a * 3 + 1 will be equivalent to something like (b = Sum(Mult(a, Number(3)), Number(1)). Once you have something like this you can change the value of a with an accessor and then request the top node to be reevaluated, which gives you the value you need.

There are probably a couple of implementations already out there. It's not hard to implement, but it'a bit tedious to define all the classes and implicit conversions needed. It get's more complicated if you want to optimize the evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Functional Reactive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) in general, and [Elm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm_(programming_language)) in particular, which provide that kind of computational style in a functional programming environment.